Turn on speaker with microphone inserted
I have a microphone that I need for better input sound, I want to be able to talk to others on it so they hear me better, but the microphone doesn't have any headphones attached to it so I can't hear any output sounds when the microphone is in.
Is there a setting or something that let's me turn on the speaker when the microphone is inserted?

Possible dupe: How to force the phone earpiece to be used when an external microphone (headset) is connected?
